# Simple yet confusing: if $ f^2(x)=g^2(x)(x^2+1) $ then $gcd( f^2(x),g^2(x))=(x^2+1)$?

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, divisibility

As mentioned in the title:

f(x) and g(x) are polynomials above the Rationals field. 
if $  f^2(x)=g^2(x)(x^2+1) $ then does it mean that $ gcd( f^2(x),g^2(x))=(x^2+1) $? 
or maybe it isn't the greatest common divisor but some divisor that was found.

By Euclid's algorithm it seems that's exactly the gcd, but it seems logical to me that maybe it's some divisor as well.. 
please help? Thanks

Comment: Put $g(x)=1$. Then the $\gcd$ should be $1$, not $x^2+1$.

Comment: And since $f^2$ is divisible by $g^2$ then $\gcd(f^2,g^2)=g^2$.

Comment: I'm dividng by $g^2$. why the gcd is not $x^2+1$ by Euclids?

Comment: You are probably iterating in Euclid's by taking the quotient instead of the remainder. Review Euclid's algorithm. You divide $f^2$ by $g^2$ and get remainder zero. When you get remainder zero in Euclid's algorithm, you stop, and the previous divisor was the $\gcd$.

Comment: I understand what you're saying, but if I divide by $1+x^2$ I get that this is the gcd? ($1+x^2$ is not 0 because I'm talking about the Rationals)

Comment: No, you clearly don't understand what I am saying. Read first Euclid's algorithm. You don't divide by $(x^2+1)$ because you don't even know if $g^2$ is divisible by $x^2+1$. The input of Euclid's algorithm should be the polynomials you are computing the $\gcd$ of. In this case, $f^2$ and $g^2$. So, you divide $f^2$ by $g^2$ and get remainder $0$ because $f^2$ is divisible by $g^2$. Since the remainder is zero, Euclid's algorithm stops and the output of the algorithm is the last divisor used. In this case, $g^2$.

Comment: Are $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ supposed to be polynomials - and if so, what coefficients are allowed. Questions of divisibility depend critically on what types of divisors may be allowed, and you haven't yet specified this.

Comment: @MarkBennet I edited the question

Comment: Is $f^2(x)$ the same as $f(x)\cdot f(x)$ or is it $f(f(x))$. With the first interpretation, if $f(x)$ is a polynomial, $g(x)$ isn't (it could be over the field of characteristic $2$ when we have $x^2+1=(x+1)^2$).

Comment: why it is not? can you give a quick proof why it is not polynomial

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that, if $f$ and $g$ are polynomials with rational coefficients, then the equation $f^2=(x^2+1)g^2$ is impossible unless $f$ and $g$ are constants. This is for the same reason that $a^2=2b^2$ is impossible if $a$ and $b$ are to be integers, unless $a=b=0$. The integers form a unique factorization domain, and 2 is not a square; the polynomials over the rationals form a unique factorization domain, and $x^2+1$ is not a square.

If $f$ and $g$ are constants, then necessarily $f=\pm g$. If they are nonzero constants, then, as polynomials with rational coefficients, their (monic) gcd is 1, and certainly not $x^2+1$.

Answer (score 0):

HINT. The gcd of two or more integers is the largest positive integer that divides the numbers without a remainder. This definition can also be extended to polynomials. For example:
$$3x^2 - 12 = 3·(x - 2)·(x + 2)$$ 
$$3x^3 + 24 = 3·(x + 2)· (x^2 - 2x + 4)$$ 
$$6x + 12 = 2 ·3·(x + 2)$$
Then $gcd=3(x+2)$. In the our case we have that, since $f^2$ is divisible by $g^2$ then $gcd=g^2$.

Comment: but $f^2$ is divisible by $1+x^2$ as well because it is not zero (I'm talking above the Rational field), then is it the gcd ?

Comment: but $g^2$ isn't divisible for (1+x^2).